# How to send post with jquery onsubmit but still send form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to trigger this function, which uses the jquery's post method, when a form is submitted:

```
function update_point_session(){
    $.post('/update_point_session/', 
           {session: true},
           function(data){}
    );
    return true;
}
```

I uses the `onsubmit` to trigger it.

The problem is that it won't send it when the form is submitted. But if I `return false;` it will (though the form itself, of course, will not). It looks as if the `$.post` is not send before the page is directed to another one by the form..

So I think I somehow have to `return true;` AFTER the `$.post`. I tried to do this by putting it inside `function(data){}` but it did not work..

How can I send BOTH the post from jquery and from the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do.

### Make the AJAX synchronous

Since `$.post` is, [according to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,  
    data: data,
    success: success  
    dataType: dataType
});
```

You can simply replace `$.post` with the equivalent `$.ajax` call, and also add `async: false` to the options. This will submit the form with AJAX and then, due to the `return true;` from the function, will also let the browser post the form normally.

### Submit the form only after the AJAX completes

This involves some event handler juggling:

```
// attach submit event handler to the form
$("#myform").submit(function() { 
    // Handler immediately detaches itself, so that
    // we don't have an infinite loop when we call
    // $(this).submit() ourselves below
    $(this).unbind('submit');

    // Do the AJAX
    $.post(
        '/update_point_session/', 
        {session: true},
        function(data){
            // When the AJAX completes, tell the browser
            // to re-submit the form
            $(this).submit();
        }
    );

    // Prevent the browser from submitting it NOW,
    // because the AJAX is still running
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sync: Which by the way due to the nature of this requirement is better than other ideas like preventing the submit and resubmitting after the async response. This is due to the fact that the user would be able to edit fields during the wait. So sometimes sync request are not so evil :)

Comment: The sync way was the smoothest and easiest way! Thank you for the detailed description and different solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for the asynchronous post to complete before unloading the page. You can send back a redirect url from the server as json something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    $.post(this.action || '/update_point_session/', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        // send back a redirect url from the server
        if(data.url) location.href = data.url;
    });
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: I think that tmpethick wants to send both the form and the ajax

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
$('form#myFormId').submit(function(evt){
    var form = $(this);
    evt.preventDefault(); // Prevents default submission
    $.post('/update_point_session/', {session: true}, function(data){
        form.unbind('submit'); //Unbind js submit event
        form.get(0).submit(); //submit the form
    });
});
```